# Need to achieve specific particles behavior that will embrace the object

Tags: particles, hair, force-fields

I am trying to force hair particles to clump in groups, then embrace the object from different sides, and when the object ends the tips should become curly (or turbulent). I tried a lot of force fields and different collision settings but still not even close. Maybe somebody could help me with this effect? I do not mind if it is hair particles or emitter path converted to a mesh (or any other option that might help to achieve the effect)

Attached images: 1. What I am trying to achieve. Each green line represents the clump of particles (it is not planned as just a literal 4 curves;)

The second screenshot displays how big the clumps should be. By now they follow the right directions but: overlap, doesn't embrace the sphere and if I add turbulence it affects not only tips but also the middle parts of the hair

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for a Hair Particle System with Dynamics enabled. To "embrace the sphere", be sure that: 1) the Sphere has Collision modifier; 2) create a "Force" and place it in the middle of the sphere, with an intensity of something like -20. And in the Hair :: Field Weights, perhaps set -1 for Gravity (or set it to zero).

Here is an exmple [image]

Comment: For some reason, I can't see the hair on your example (just doesn't show up) But I think I've got the point and I was able to recreate it. But there is still one problem: the tips stay stick to the sphere. But they have to keep growing farther, just leave the sphere and start curling. How can I change the behavior of the tips without ruining the middle part and roots?